# Creating a Visual Studio project template that references external libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2012

We're attempting to create a new project template that has references to external libraries like StructureMap and Entity Framework. However, when we create a project from the template the libraries are linked but the link is broken because of file path issues.

I would either like to have NuGet know to go download the packages on when creating the new project, or have some way to package the libraries in the project template.

Answer (score 0):

You may want have a look at this post: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/06/creating-a-custom-asp-net-mvc-project-template.aspx

Although its about MVC the details about the very limited NuGet support for project templates is relevant to your question.

You could consider creating a custom IWizard for your template http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx but in short I don't believe there is an easy answer to what you are trying to do yet.